# Associate specific SLF4J logger with Jetty embedded

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jetty, slf4j

I'm trying to assign a specific SLF4J logger instance to my Jetty embedded server using the following lines of code:

```
Logger myLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Web Server");
Log.setLog((org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Logger) myLogger)
```

where `myLogger` is an instance of `org.slf4j.Logger`.  This returns a `ClassCastException` since

```
org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Logger`
```

How then can I go about this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want ...

```java
// Do this at the earliest possible point in your code.
Log.setLog(new org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4Log());
```

Then just use your slf4j loggers normally.